# Calculating max shardSize and fileDimensions to avoid tiling large raster exports in Earth Engine

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, export, large-datasets

I am exporting a very large raster in Google Earth Engine to my Google Drive.  I am trying to keep my exported raster to 1 file to avoid additional processing to merge the tiles (e.g. GDAL merge in QGIS).  I know you can specify larger `shardSize` and `fileDimensions` to increase the size of your exported raster tiles.

For example, based on [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-earth-engine-developers/shardsize%7Csort:date/google-earth-engine-developers/bCHE0Ehly2Y/7ULZdMH9CAAJ), I've been setting my `shardSize` to 1024 and playing around with my `fileDimensions` by trial and error.  So I arbitrarily set my `fileDimensions` to 1024*17 = 17408 but return an error on the following...

```
  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: large_raster
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e13,
    region: aoi,
    shardSize: 1024, // must be no greater than 1024; larger shardSize --> larger tile
    fileDimensions: 17408 // must be a multiple of 1024 and no greater than 131072
  });

Error: File dimensions are too large for the number of bands and data type: the total file size requested is 32728154112 bytes before compression (108 bytes per pixel), but must be less than 17179869184 bytes.
```

...then I will adjust my `fileDimensions` to the next lowest multiple of 1024 (e.g. 1024*16=16384), try to export, and see if I return an error.

But, I want to calculate my max `fileDimensions` from the get-go without this trial and error.  Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three limitations on `fileDimensions`. It need to be a multiple of `shardSize`, it cannot be larger than `131072`, and the size of the file before compression cannot exceed `17179869183` bytes. To come up with a way to find the maximum valid `fileDimensions` is a tricky little problem.

My take on this require you to specify the number of bits the pixels in each layer have. I couldn't come up with a way to automatically figure this value out based on an image. It would be great if someone else have an idea how to do that.

```
var image = ee.Image(0).float()
var region = ee.Geometry(Map.getBounds(true))
var scale = 30
var shardSize = 256 // Will not really change your tile size

var size = imageSize({
    image: image,
    region: ee.Geometry(Map.getBounds(true)),
    scale: scale, 
    bits: 32, 
    shardSize: shardSize
  })

print(size)

// Export require client-side objects, so we evaluate to
// get the fileDimensions as a client-side object.
size.evaluate(function (size) {
  try {
    Export.image.toDrive({
      image: image,
      scale: scale,
      maxPixels: 1e13,
      region: region,
      shardSize: shardSize,
      fileDimensions: size.fileDimensions
    })
  } catch(e) {
    print('ERROR: ', e)
  }
})  

/**
 * Calculates information about the image size.
 * 
 * Arguments:
 * 
 *   params - an object with:
 * 
 *     image - the ee.Image to get the size for
 *     region - the ee.Geometry to include
 *     scale - resolution in meters per pixel
 *     bits - the number of bits for each band in the image
 *       float (32-bit), double (64-bit), int (16-bit)
 *       int8, uint8, int16, uint16, int32, uint32 
 *       are 8-, 16-, and 32-bit, as their name hints
 *     shardSize - size in pixels of the shards Google split your processing work into
 * 
 * Returns an ee.Dictionary with:
 * 
 *   fileDimensions - largest possible fileDimensions when exporting
 *   fileSize - the uncompressed file size of each tile
 *   imageDimensions - total image dimensions
 *   imageSize - the uncompressed file size of the whole image
 */ 
function imageSize(params) {
  var image = params.image
  var region = params.region
  var scale = params.scale || 30
  var bits = params.bits || 64
  var shardSize = params.shardSize || 256

  var numberOfBands = image.bandNames().size()
  var bytesPerPixel = numberOfBands.multiply(bits).divide(8)
  var MAX_BYTES = 17179869183
  var MAX_SIDE = 131072
  var maxMultipleSide = prevMultiple(MAX_SIDE, shardSize)
  var maxPixels = ee.Number(MAX_BYTES).divide(bytesPerPixel).floor()

  var coordinates = ee.List(region.bounds().coordinates().get(0))
  var sw = ee.Geometry.Point(coordinates.get(0))
  var se = ee.Geometry.Point(coordinates.get(1))
  var ne = ee.Geometry.Point(coordinates.get(2))
  var totalWidth = sw.distance(se).divide(scale).int()
  var totalHeight = se.distance(ne).divide(scale).int()
  var clampedWidth = clampUp(totalWidth)
  var clampedHeight = clampUp(totalHeight)
  var dimensionsOptions = ee.List([
    [clampedWidth, clampDown(maxPixels.divide(clampedWidth))],
    [clampDown(maxPixels.divide(clampedHeight)), clampedHeight]
  ])
  var optionSizes = dimensionsOptions.map(function (dimensions) {
    return ee.List(dimensions).reduce(ee.Reducer.product())
  })
  var dimensions = ee.List(dimensionsOptions.sort(optionSizes).get(1))

  return ee.Dictionary({
    imageDimensions: ee.List([totalWidth, totalHeight]),
    imageSize: bytesPerPixel.multiply(totalWidth).multiply(totalHeight),
    fileDimensions: dimensions,
    fileSize: bytesPerPixel.multiply(dimensions.reduce(ee.Reducer.product()))
  })

  function clampUp(side) {
    return nextMultiple(side).min(maxMultipleSide)
  }

  function clampDown(side) {
    return prevMultiple(side).min(maxMultipleSide)
  }

  function nextMultiple(side) {
    return ee.Number(side)
      .divide(shardSize).ceil()
      .multiply(shardSize)
  }

  function prevMultiple(side) {
    return ee.Number(side)
      .divide(shardSize).floor()
      .multiply(shardSize)
  } 
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/eea7d691959a7c25a9206a107cea638d

Comment: Is it possible to use a try/catch within a function in the server-side? Similar to this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/367799/how-can-i-restart-the-loop-or-skip-the-error, but with a function which latter is mapped to a list of dates?

Answer (score -1):

The Python equivalent to get the file size would be

```py
import ee

# Initialize Earth Engine
ee.Initialize()

# Define the image and region
image = ee.Image(0).float()
region = ee.Geometry(ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR").first().geometry())

# Define scale and shardSize
scale = 30
shardSize = 256

# Define the size function
def imageSize(params):
    image = params['image']
    region = params['region']
    scale = params.get('scale', 30)
    bits = params.get('bits', 64)
    shardSize = params.get('shardSize', 256)
    
    numberOfBands = image.bandNames().size()
    bytesPerPixel = numberOfBands.multiply(bits).divide(8)
    MAX_BYTES = 17179869183
    MAX_SIDE = 131072
    maxMultipleSide = prevMultiple(MAX_SIDE)
    maxPixels = ee.Number(MAX_BYTES).divide(bytesPerPixel).floor()
    
    coordinates = ee.List(region.bounds().coordinates().get(0))
    sw = ee.Geometry.Point(coordinates.get(0))
    se = ee.Geometry.Point(coordinates.get(1))
    ne = ee.Geometry.Point(coordinates.get(2))
    totalWidth = sw.distance(se).divide(scale).int()
    totalHeight = se.distance(ne).divide(scale).int()
    clampedWidth = clampUp(totalWidth, maxMultipleSide)
    clampedHeight = clampUp(totalHeight, maxMultipleSide)
    dimensionsOptions = ee.List([
        [clampedWidth, clampDown(maxPixels.divide(clampedWidth), maxMultipleSide)],
        [clampDown(maxPixels.divide(clampedHeight), maxMultipleSide), clampedHeight]
    ])
    optionSizes = dimensionsOptions.map(lambda dimensions: ee.List(dimensions).reduce(ee.Reducer.product()))
    dimensions = ee.List(dimensionsOptions.sort(optionSizes).get(1))
    
    return ee.Dictionary({
        'imageDimensions': ee.List([totalWidth, totalHeight]),
        'imageSize': bytesPerPixel.multiply(totalWidth).multiply(totalHeight),
        'fileDimensions': dimensions,
        'fileSize': bytesPerPixel.multiply(dimensions.reduce(ee.Reducer.product()))
    })

def clampUp(side, maxMultipleSide):
    return nextMultiple(side).min(maxMultipleSide)

def clampDown(side, maxMultipleSide):
    return prevMultiple(side).min(maxMultipleSide)

def nextMultiple(side):
    return ee.Number(side).divide(shardSize).ceil().multiply(shardSize)

def prevMultiple(side):
    return ee.Number(side).divide(shardSize).floor().multiply(shardSize)

# Create the params dictionary
params = {
    'image': image,
    'region': region,
    'scale': scale,
    'bits': 32,
    'shardSize': shardSize
}

# Call the size function and print the result
size = imageSize(params)
print(size.getInfo())
```