# How can I restart the loop or skip the error?

Tags: google-earth-engine, loop, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I set up a loop to extract cloudiness in multiple places, but if there is no image in one place in the loop, GEE will report an error.I want to loop to a place where there is no image and the loop can continue to the next place.Below is my code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  var id = ee.Feature(listall.get(i)).getInfo()['properties']['FieldID'];
  var nm = ee.Feature(listall.get(i)).getInfo()['properties']['FactoryNam'];
  var addre = ee.Feature(listall.get(i)).getInfo()['properties']['FactoryAdd'];
  var Lat = ee.Feature(listall.get(i)).getInfo()['properties']['lat'];
  var Lng = ee.Feature(listall.get(i)).getInfo()['properties']['Lng'];
  var x1 = ee.Feature(listall.get(i)).getInfo()['properties']['Lng1'];
  var y1 = ee.Feature(listall.get(i)).getInfo()['properties']['lat1'];
  var x2 = ee.Feature(listall.get(i)).getInfo()['properties']['Lng2'];
  var y2 = ee.Feature(listall.get(i)).getInfo()['properties']['lat2'];
  var x3 = ee.Feature(listall.get(i)).getInfo()['properties']['Lng3'];
  var y3 = ee.Feature(listall.get(i)).getInfo()['properties']['lat3'];
  var x4 = ee.Feature(listall.get(i)).getInfo()['properties']['Lng4'];
  var y4 = ee.Feature(listall.get(i)).getInfo()['properties']['lat4'];
  
  var firm = ee.Geometry.Polygon([ [x1, y1], [x2, y2], [x3, y3], [x4, y4] ]);
  var center = ee.Geometry.Point(x1, y1);
  var pol = center.buffer(5000, 500);
  var outer = pol.difference(firm);
    
  var sr = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR");
  var t1 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1");
    
  //卫星图像筛选
  var date_rg = ee.DateRange('2013-04-01', '2013-04-15'); 
  var SR = sr.filterDate(date_rg)        
    .filterBounds(firm)
    .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
    .first(1)
    .clip(pol); 
     
  var T1= t1.filterDate(date_rg) 
      .filterBounds(firm)
      .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
      .first(1)
      .clip(pol);
```

Comment: Google Earth Engine works quite differently to Javascript. You would almost never use for loops and instead use `.map()`. Refer to this for help on how map works: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/feature_collection_mapping

Comment: Besides avoiding for-loops, it is also highly recommended to not use the `.getInfo()` command. It will interfere with GEE's lazy evaluation and it will slow down your script. See [this page](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/client_server) for more details

Answer (score 1):

You can easily catch the error that may happen in the main loop by using `try {...} catch (error) {...}` structure. Here is managed errors sample code:

```
var T1_SR = []
var T1 = []

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  ...
  var firm = ee.Geometry.Polygon([ [x1, y1], [x2, y2], [x3, y3], [x4, y4] ]);
  var center = ee.Geometry.Point(x1, y1);
  var pol = center.buffer(5000, 500);
  var outer = pol.difference(firm);
    
  var sr = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR");
  var t1 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1");

  var date_rg = ee.DateRange('2013-04-01', '2013-04-15'); 

  try {
    var SR = sr.filterDate(date_rg)        
      .filterBounds(firm)
      .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
      .first(1)
      .clip(pol); 
  } catch (error) {
    // error.message
    // log the locations that don't have images
    T1_SR.push(firm)
  }

  try {
    var T1 = t1.filterDate(date_rg)        
      .filterBounds(firm)
      .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
      .first(1)
      .clip(pol); 
  } catch (error) {
    // error.message
    // log the locations that don't have images
    T1.push(firm)
  }
}
```

Above, I've added two empty array (`T1_SR` and `T1`) to push locations that doesn't contain images of two interesting collections into them.
You can also use `error` object to handle different exceptions as this object has a `message` attribute.
Because this loop is using `try {...} catch (error) {...}` block, it will work fine until the loop ends and you can log the locations without images.