# GEE Export.image.toDrive file is not split in tiles

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to export a large image to my drive (# of pixels exceeds 1e13 which is the maximum value even after adjusting MaxPixels).
In the documentation it states that the image will automatically be split up in tiles, but I just get an error that the file is too large. Especially after you specify a fileDimensions value. Why do i still get an error?

This is the code:

```
Export.image.toDrive({ 
      image: Image,
      description: value,
      folder: outputDirectory,
      fileNamePrefix: value,
      scale: spatialResolution,
      shardSize: 256,
      fileDimensions: 256
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying a `fileDimensions` that is way to big. This would be an image with `2560000*2560000` pixels, way over the GeoTIFF [4 GB](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000279.shtml) limit. Try to export your image using a smaller value for `fileDimensions`.

Maybe [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/360062/154371) answer can be of help?

Comment: Thanks for the response, the piece above does indeed cause the tiles to be too large. However, when I change this value to something that should work theoretically I still get the same error. I'll change the code in the question

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime i've found the problem. The Image that I was trying to export didn't have any specific information regarding the extent associated to it. After clipping the Images with a geoJson detailing the extent of the research area, the export worked as expected.