# Making large Sentinel-2 images export as single image

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have a large image dataset on GEE and calculated the median. When I print, I have confirmed it is a single image. However, when I export to google drive it is multiple GeoTiffs.

Is there a way to make the export a single image?

see code below:

```
//1 Mask Clouds
function maskS2clouds(sentColl) {
var qa = sentColl.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return sentColl.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}
//2. Define Sentinel-2 Image Collection
var sentColl = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED')
                  .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2023-01-01')
                 .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(06, 8, 'month')) 
                  .filterMetadata ('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 10)
                  .filterBounds(AOI)
                  //.select(['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8'])
                  .map(maskS2clouds);
                 
print(sentColl);

//4. Compute the median in each band and each pixel and then select RGBI bands. Band names are B2_Median, B3_Median etc.
 var imgMed = sentColl.reduce(ee.Reducer.median())
.select('B2_median', 'B3_median', 'B4_median', 'B8_median');
print(imgMed)
 //5. Output image. Add it to map.
var VisualizeP = {
bands:['B2_median', 'B3_median', 'B4_median'],
min:0.012,
max:0.145,
gamma:1.30,
};
//Map.addLayer(imgMed,VisualizeP);
Map.centerObject(AOI,10);

//Clip image
var NSSent = imgMed.clip(AOI)
Map.addLayer(NSSent,VisualizeP, '2019_2023NSSS');

//Export Sentinel-2 Mosaic
Export.image.toDrive({
  image:NSSent,
  description: '2019_2023NSSS',
  scale: 10,
  region: AOI,
  
  maxPixels:16792443500
})
print(NSSent)
//Calculate NDVI using the Median  Image
var ndvi = NSSent.normalizedDifference(['B8_median', 'B4_median']).rename('NDVI');
print(ndvi)
//Display NDVI
Map.addLayer(ndvi, {min:-1, max:1, palette: ['blue', 'yellow', 'green']}, 'NDVI');
//Export NDVI to drive
Export.image.toDrive({
  image:ndvi,
  description: '2019_2023NDVI',
  scale: 10,
  region: AOI,
  maxPixels: 16792443500
})

//Calculate NDWI
var ndwi = NSSent.normalizedDifference(['B3_median','B8_median'])
//Display NDWI
Map.addLayer(ndwi, {min:-1, max:1, palette: ['yellow', 'green', 'blue']}, 'NDWI');
//Export NDWI to drive
Export.image.toDrive({
  image:ndwi,
  description: '2019_2023NDWI',
  scale: 10,
  region: AOI,
  maxPixels: 16792443500
})
```

Answer (score 0):

A GeoTIFF [cannot](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000279.shtml) be larger than 4 GB:

> Like the TIFF format, GeoTIFF uses 32-bit offsets, limiting its extent
> to 4 gigabytes

To prevent you from running into this limit, EE will tile the image for you (as you noticed). You can control the tiling with `fileDimensions` in `toDrive()`. Maybe you can pick a big enough value to export your particular image as a single GeoTIFF. You didn't share your AOI, so it's impossible to say for sure.

You can look at [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/360062/154371) answer for details on maximizing `fileDimensions`.